# oracle order by: order results symmetrically

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, unpivot

Circuit have two end points(legs) and each leg is connected to device. SO result is symmetric to circuit at each side say A and B. 
I am looking to sort my SQL results as below:

```
component location pathelement
-------------------------------
device_A    A       A_DD1
device_A    A       A_DD2
device_A    A       A_DD3
leg_A       L_A     A_LL1
leg_A       L_A     A_LL2
circuit     Center  CCCC
leg_B       L_B     B_LL1
leg_B       L_B     B_LL2
device_B    B       B_DD2
device_B    B       B_DD3
```

.
my query is:

```
select component,location,pathelement,sortorder from 
(select c.name circuit,l.name leg,d.name d,
c.location c_loc,l_pe.location l_loc,d_pe.location d_loc,
c_pe.pathelements c_pe,l_pe.pathelements l_pe,d_pe.pathelements d_pe,
1 d_sortorder,2 l_sortorder,3 c_sortorder
from circuit c,leg l,device d,
(select circuitid,location,pathelements from circuit_details) c_pe,
(select legid,location,pathelements from leg_details)l_pe,
(select deviceid,location,pathelements from device_details)d_pe
where
c.circuit2leg=l.legid(+) 
and l.leg2device=d.deviceid(+)
and c.circuitid=c_pe.circuitid(+)
and l.legid=l_pe.legid(+)
and d.deviceid=d_pe.deviceid(+)
and c.name=<some_text>)
Unpivot((component,location,pathelement,sortorder) for c in 
((circuit,c_loc,c_pe,c_sortorder),(leg.l_loc,l_pe,l_sortorder),(device,d_loc,d_pe,d_sortorder))) order by sortorder;
```

Actual output was:

```
component location pathelement
-------------------------------
device_A    A       A_DD1
device_A    A       A_DD2
device_A    A       A_DD3
device_B    B       B_DD2
device_B    B       B_DD3
leg_A       L_A     A_LL1
leg_A       L_A     A_LL2
leg_B       L_B     B_LL1
leg_B       L_B     B_LL2
circuit     Center  CCCC
```

Comment: You select 4 columns, but only show us 3 of them. The one you order by is missing...

Comment: What's the expected result if you add some C items?

Comment: Don't you miss a leg_A in your example?

Comment: user3427970, sadly to say, this is not a good code and it should be rewritten from scratch. I suggest you'll give samples for the original data and ask assistent for the full query and not only for the sort.

Comment: `component` and `location` seem to contain more ar less the same data (with `location` being only an abbreviation for `component`). So you can either use one or the other for sorting. Can there be any other values apart from those shown?

Comment: Is there only data for one circuit in the table? Will that remain so? (I wonder because there is a `circuitid` in the tables, but you neither filter by it nor show it in the results.)

Comment: Yes only one circuit will be there. That have two ends(A and B legs) and each leg is connected to a device. each component (ie. circuit,leg,device) may have n number of **PEs** internally. Requirement is wanted to display in this order **device-leg-circuit-leg-device**. I just mentioned data for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the data from the tables and glue the results together. As you know all possible locations in advance, you can use a case expression to apply a sort order.

```
select c.name, cd.location, cd.pathelement 
from circuit c 
join circuit_details cd on cd.circuitid = c.circuitid 
where c.name = <some_text>
UNION ALL
select l.name, ld.location, ld.pathelement 
from leg l 
join leg_details ld on ld.circuitid = l.circuitid 
where l.circuitid = (select c.circuitid from circuit c where c.name = <some_text>)
UNION ALL
select d.name, dd.location, dd.pathelement 
from device d 
join device_details dd on dd.circuitid = d.circuitid 
where d.circuitid = (select c.circuitid from circuit c where c.name = <some_text>)
ORDER BY 
  case location
    when 'A' then -2
    when 'L_A' then -1
    when 'Center' then 0
    when 'L_B' then 1
    when 'B' then 2
  end,
  pathelement;
```

Better would be to have a lookup table for the five locations and their sort keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally nested case condition worked in this case. Here is the modified query.

```
select component,location,pathelement,
case when location='A' then 
case when LTRIM(component,'_A')='device' then -2
when LTRIM(component,'_A')='leg' then -1 end
when location='Center' then 0
when location='B' then 
case when LTRIM(component,'_B')='device' then 2
when LTRIM(component,'_B')='leg' then 1 end as ord
from 
(select c.name circuit,l.name leg,d.name d,
c.location c_loc,l_pe.location l_loc,d_pe.location d_loc,
c_pe.pathelements c_pe,l_pe.pathelements l_pe,d_pe.pathelements d_pe
from circuit c,leg l,device d,
(select circuitid,location,pathelements from circuit_details) c_pe,
(select legid,location,pathelements from leg_details)l_pe,
(select deviceid,location,pathelements from device_details)d_pe
where
c.circuit2leg=l.legid(+) 
and l.leg2device=d.deviceid(+)
and c.circuitid=c_pe.circuitid(+)
and l.legid=l_pe.legid(+)
and d.deviceid=d_pe.deviceid(+)
and c.name=<some_text>)
Unpivot((component,location,pathelement,sortorder) for c in 
((circuit,c_loc,c_pe),(leg.l_loc,l_pe),(device,d_loc,d_pe))) order by ord,pathelement;
```

Result:

```
component location pathelement ord
-------------------------------
device_A    A       A_DD1       -2
device_A    A       A_DD2       -2  
device_A    A       A_DD3       -2
leg_A       L_A     A_LL1       -1  
leg_A       L_A     A_LL2       -1
circuit     Center  CCCC        0   
leg_B       L_B     B_LL1       1
leg_B       L_B     B_LL2       1
device_B    B       B_DD2       2
device_B    B       B_DD3       2
```